# Получение информации по автомобилю по номеру

Tags: поиск-api

Слышал, что у официального сайта ГИБДД есть API, но так и не смог его найти.
Существует море сервисов, которые предоставляют информацию ТС по его номеру, при этом на официальном сайте ГИБДД есть только проверка по vin номеру. Откуда сервисы берут информацию по ТС, имея только номер ТС?

Comment: Так у них и спросите. Или может быть вы хотели спросить у ruSO где ***вам*** взять API?

Comment: Я спрашивал, все утаивают эту информацию. Хотелось бы просто узнать, откуда сервисы черпают информацию по тс, имея только номер тс

Answer (score 0):

взаимодействие через http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/portal/

ГИБДД Предоставление сведений об административных правонарушениях в области дорожного движения: http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/portal/services.jsp#!/F/6GIBDDPredostavleniesveden/1.00/p00smev/SID0003030

на странице есть руководство пользователя)

Comment: Спасибо, это по получению информации по штрафам, есть информация по получению информации по тс?

Answer (score 0):

У ГИБДД нет API.
Качественно проверить автомобиль можно только через VIN и через парсинг сайта ГИБДД
Все сервисы работаю по косвенным данным и за счет уже накопленной своей базы.

Так что ищите способ парсить сайт ГИБДД